# How to get into CLI Mode of CentOS7 Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, debian-jessie

I'm using **Debian Jessie** with GUI as host OS on my machine. I installed **VirtualBox** 5.18 along with its extension file. I created a **CentOS** 7 Server with GUI Virtual Machine. Whenever I press CTRL+ALT+F1~F6, the screen always takes me to **Debian**'s CLI screen. What I want is **CentOS** CLI screen. Anyone???

Comment: According to http://askubuntu.com/questions/542328/send-ctrlaltf1-crtlaltf7-into-virtualbox you could use RightCTRL + F1

Comment: not working... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host button and F1/F2 etc will do it for you. The host button inserts `Ctrl + Alt` on the guest system.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!!

In Debain, use **CTRL+ALT+F1~F6** to get into CLI. **CTRL+ALT+F7** to GUI.

In CentOS, use **HOST+F2~F6** to get into CLI. **HOST+F1** to GUI.